# Missing ".NETFramework" directory in "Program Files" directory

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, windows-7-x64

I have a 64bit Windows 7 development machine and I have the following directories:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v3.5
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1
```

But for the 64bit `Program Files` directory, I only have:

```
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5
```

So why `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework` is missing? Am I forgetting to install something?

Comment: Checking my 64bit Windows 7 development machine, I have the same. What you are probably seeing is your Visual Studio 2013 having installed the 4.0, 4.5, and 4.5.1. It is a 32 bit app, so it only installed actual .Net framework it needed.

Comment: This is entirely normal.  64-bit compilers look in c:\program files and 32-bit compilers look in c:\program files (x86).  All the compilers you use are 32-bit compilers.  There is one you have on your machine that is a 64-bit compiler, it is not relevant.

Comment: @StarPilot, the project reference `Path` for `System.Data` is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.Data.dll` when the `Target Platform` was set to `x86`, but it's the same even if I change to `x64`. Shouldn't I expect to see `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.Data.dll` instead?

Comment: According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms241064(v=vs.110).aspx , 64 bit .Net applications can use the 32 bit .Net assemblies. So anything compiled with 2.0 or newer will run 64 bit preferred, but doesn't need special assemblies to do so. You have all those assemblies under 32 bit because your compiler is 32 bit, but the user's jitter will figure out what is best for his set up unless you overwrote that by building particular flavors.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the page:

http://getdotnet.azurewebsites.net/target-dotnet-platforms.html

Select the framework you need and install it, it will create the folders for you and you can use it then.

Comment: website not available.

Comment: @BlueBurnTechnologies I am afraid that you will have to search for it again, as its about 4 years answer.